# Why is measure theory needed to understand continuous random variables and probability density functions in particular?

Tags: probability, continuous-data, measure-theory

Prefacing the question with the fact that I have no knowledge of measure theory. I would prefer a conceptual answer, as there already many mathematical ones.

Also, why don't we need measure theory to understand discrete random variables?

Comment: Measure theory is *essential* even for understanding discrete variables, such as stochastic processes on the integers with discrete marginal distributions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am reading "Deep Learning" and they make the remark at section 3.12 that to develop a proper formal understanding of continuous variables and probability density functions one would need to understand measure theory. Since they did not make that statement about discrete random variables it was my assumption that the statement was not applicable to the discrete case. Any reason you think why they would have preferred to make that statement about the continuous case rather than the discrete one?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea why someone would make such statements.  It's possible to advance quite far in theoretical statistics without measure theory, especially if you avoid doing much with stochastic processes.  However, the modern tendency is to introduce measure theory at a fairly early stage, perhaps because it is both conceptually and theoretically so powerful.

Comment: What concepts do you find so powerful that you could recommend me to look up on?

Comment: Look up anything related to Martingales.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You arguably don't need measure theory to understand continuous random variables at all; those are just the random variables which are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.
For most intents and purposes, the Riemann integral is sufficient in that case.
After all, most commonly used probability densities have very nice regularity properties.

Measure theory is needed, for example, when you need to justify things like the existence of sequences of random variables with prescribed joint distributions, or stochastic processes more generally (e.g., try proving that Brownian motion exists without measure theoretic results like the Kolmogorov extension and continuity theorems).
Another benefit of using measure theory is that it unifies the seemingly similar but distinct continuous and discrete worlds, and allows talking about random variables which are neither.
Elementary treatments of probability often duplicate effort by proving a result in the discrete case and then in the continuous case.
Using measure theory, one can sometimes prove both (and more) at the same time with a proof that might better reveal the important factors at play.

Finally, why isn't measure theory needed in the discrete case?
This is arguably because the dominating measure involved (counting measure) is so easy to work with. For one, null sets don't matter, because the only set with zero counting measure is the empty set.
Secondly, most calculations with discrete random variables amount to regular sums (albeit sometimes infinite).
This makes problems involving discrete random variables tractable even with a very limited mathematical toolkit at your disposal.

Comment: So the need to measure stems from the infinitesimal nature of continuous variables, which by definition is not needed in the discrete case. Correct?

Comment: @Nicolas I wouldn't put it that way. Like I said in my answer, you can have a good understanding of continuous random variables without knowing measure theory. In practice, working with continuous random variables means integrating functions defined on intervals, which you can do this in many cases using just what you learned in calculus. Measure theory really shines at providing a common framework for all of probability theory (and, as a result, statistics and a large part of machine learning)

Comment: @Nicolas That being said, measure theory is more of a theoretical tool than a practical one, although personally I think it's very interesting for its own sake

Comment: If I may add my 2 cents as a non-mathematician: I have never formally learned measure theory, but have found that my understanding especially of random variables and densities has improved greatly by gaining intuition about measure theory's "calculus". As you say, unifying multiple formalisms under one thing talking about densities with respect to some measure is very releaving; other gains are a deeper understanding of how Bayes theorem works with mixtures of discrete and continuos variables ("shouldn't the probability be zero?"), or everything involving changes and Radon-Nikodym derivatives.

Comment: @phipsgabler well said!